# Angular custom filter into javascript only

Tags: angularjs

I have some checkboxes and a list. I have made a custom filter to filter the results of that list according to the checkbox that is selected.
The problem is that I plan to have quite a lot of these checkboxes filtering the results so I would like to move all aspects of the filtering into the javascript. I have seen that this is possible by adding it  into the controller but I have not been able to. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/webgremlin/qpyngzu8/

html

```
<div ng-app="someApp">
    <div ng-controller="checkboxCtrl">
        <label ng-repeat="tree in trees">
            {{ tree.name }}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="tree.selected"/>
        </label>
    </div>   
    <hr />
    <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in listItems | filterByCategory : trees">
                {{ item.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>     
</div>
```

js

```
var someApp = angular.module('someApp', []);

someApp.factory('checkboxFactory', function() {
    var checkboxFactory = [
        { name: 'item 1', item: 1 },
        { name: 'item 2', item: 2 },
        { name: 'item 3', item: 3 }
    ];
    return checkboxFactory;
});

someApp.factory('listFactory', function() {
    var listFactory = [
        { name: 'list item 01', item: 1 },
        { name: 'list item 02', item: 2 },
        { name: 'list item 03', item: 3 },
        { name: 'list item 04', item: 1 },
        { name: 'list item 05', item: 2 },
        { name: 'list item 06', item: 3 },
        { name: 'list item 07', item: 1 },
        { name: 'list item 08', item: 2 },
        { name: 'list item 09', item: 3 },
        { name: 'list item 10', item: 1 }
    ];
    return listFactory;
});


someApp.filter('filterByCategory', function() {
    return function(input, trees) {
        console.log(input, trees);
        var ret =[];
        for (var i in input){
            var match = false;
            for (var j in trees){
                if (trees[j].selected && trees[j].item == input[i].item){
                   ret.push(input[i]);   
                }
            }
        }
        if (ret.length > 0){
            return ret;
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    };
  })

someApp.controller('checkboxCtrl', ['$scope','checkboxFactory', 
function($scope, checkboxFactory) {
    $scope.trees = checkboxFactory;
}]);

someApp.controller('listCtrl', ['$scope','checkboxFactory','listFactory', 
function($scope, checkboxFactory,listFactory) {
    $scope.trees = checkboxFactory;
    $scope.listItems = listFactory;
    console.log($scope.listItems);

}]);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use your filterByCategory filter in your controller?  Or you want to rewrite the filter functionality as a function on your controller?

Comment: I was thinking of just using my existing filterByCategory filter in the controller, which might be why I am having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that.  Just use the `$filter` provider to look up your filterByCategory filter in your controller and apply it that way:

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/smaye81/gp4qg257/2/